# jquery select custom attr

Tags: jquery

I have a textfield where I'm adding a custom attr called maxchars and a value of 255. I can't seem to read the value, could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong.

jquery

```
var textarea = jQuery(this);
var maxlength = parseInt(textarea.attr("maxchars"));
```

html

```
<t:TextArea maxchars="255"/>
```

Comment: That's not HTML. Please show us the final HTML output.

Comment: I would also like to see what `this` is

Comment: Thanks guys, this ended up being a simple over site on my behalf. I'll prefix my custom attr with data-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[maxchars]')
```

But it's not vailid html. Set data in fron of it!
To make it html5 valid, name your attribute `data-maxchars` and use the selector `$('[data-maxchars]')`

Sample: 
HTML

```
<p maxchars="255">test</p>
```

JS:

```
var text = $('[maxchars]').text();
alert(text);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPg7W/)

Comment: Stefan, should you be setting data in front of your example?

Comment: The data suffix is a the way, the standard is define. Most browser sitll will render your page correctly (even ie6) but correctly speeking it's not standard comform. Here is an article what the data attribute is and what you should use it for: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery data attributes to do this.

See this page: http://api.jquery.com/data/

If you add an attribute like this:

```
<a id="myanchor" href=".." data-myattr="customattribute">
```

You can then access it using

```
$('#myanchor').data('myattr');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('textarea[maxchars="255"]')
```

Try this out